# Production build of React application showing trimmed componentStack when I use componentDidCatch

Tags: reactjs

In my react JS web application, I use the error boundary to catch errors in the component tree using the componentDidCatch(error, info) function.

But the error information (info.componentStack) which I receive in the development server and production(build) server are totally different. The development server shows the correct error message. But in the production server I can see the trimmed error message. Please see the below image.

[image: error message in production build]

Can you please help to solve this issue?
Do I miss any configuration for the production build to receive the proper error information using error boundary?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `displayName` to your components like:

```
SomeComponent.displayName = 'SomeComponent'
```

this will end up in componentStack

Answer (score 0):

This seems intentional in the production mode of React: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#component-stack-traces

As per the docs, it's recommended that you set up an external service to help monitor errors in your production apps.

Comment: Ok. But if the errors are not in readable/understandable format, what is the use of monitoring it using external service?

Comment: That's a great question. I'm not sure - I will pull my answer if someone comes up with something concrete